# how to access HTML child elements in protractor

Tags: html, protractor

I want to access the 'value' from the following :

- HTMLCollection [div.timeline--progress]

  - 0: div.progress

    - accessKey: "" align: "" assignedSlot: null attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 1} attributes: NamedNodeMap

      - 0: class 1: style

        - baseURI: "https://sample.com/" childNodes: NodeList [] firstChild: null isConnected: false lastChild: null localName: "style" name: "style" namespaceURI: null nextSibling: null nodeName: "style" nodeType: 2 nodeValue: "width: 15.0832%;" ownerDocument: document ownerElement: div.progress parentElement: null parentNode: null prefix: null previousSibling: null specified: true textContent: "width: 15.0832%;" value: "width: 15.0832%;" **proto**: Attr

I tried doing the following :

> let getWidth = $('.progress').getAttribute('value');

But this printed me the complete object.

I need the value from 'value' field only.

Appreciate your suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the following way. Actually, the way you tried returns a promise and it needs to resolve. Try the below way.

```
let progress = $('.elem');
let getWidth = await progress.getAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it returns unresolved promise. See the docs: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

.getAttribute(); returns a promise that needs to be resolved. You should try:

```
let getWidth = $('.progress').getAttribute('value')
    .then(function(value){
       console.log(value);
    )};
```